# PL/SQL function showing error that ::: ORA-06575: Package or function FUN_MIN is in an invalid state

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am unable to solve this, please help

> ORA-06575: Package or function FUN_MIN is in an invalid state

```
create or replace Function fun_min(a number,b number,c number)
return number as
begin
if a<c and a<b
then
return a;
else if
b<a and b<c
then
return b;
else if
c<a and c<b
then
return c;
end if;
end;
/
select fun_min(1,2,3) from dual;
```

Comment: MySQL is not Oracle's "Oracle" DB. Please tag with what you're actually using. With an ORA message this is not MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kaushik has already told you - syntax error.

I'd suggest you to use a single `RETURN` point - include additional variable (RETVAL in my example), set it to a value you'd like to return, and then `RETURN retval`.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_min (a NUMBER, b NUMBER, c NUMBER)
  2     RETURN NUMBER
  3  AS
  4     retval   NUMBER;
  5  BEGIN
  6     IF     a < c
  7        AND a < b
  8     THEN
  9        retval := a;
 10     ELSIF     b < a
 11           AND b < c
 12     THEN
 13        retval := b;
 14     ELSIF     c < a
 15           AND c < b
 16     THEN
 17        retval := c;
 18     END IF;
 19
 20     RETURN retval;
 21  END;
 22  /

Function created.
```

However, that code is *wrong*; have a look at the following example:

- min2 should have been 2
- min3 should have been 3

but both of them are NULL.

```
SQL> SELECT fun_min (1, 2, 3) min1, fun_min (2, 2, 3) min2, fun_min (3, 3, 3) min3
  2    FROM DUAL;

      MIN1       MIN2       MIN3
---------- ---------- ----------
         1

SQL>
```

So, yes - `LEAST` function might be a better choice, instead of all those IFs:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_min (a NUMBER, b NUMBER, c NUMBER)
  2     RETURN NUMBER
  3  AS
  4  BEGIN
  5     RETURN LEAST (a, b, c);
  6  END;
  7  /

Function created.

SQL> SELECT fun_min (1, 2, 3) min1, fun_min (2, 2, 3) min2, fun_min (3, 3, 3) min3
  2    FROM DUAL;

      MIN1       MIN2       MIN3
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be `ELSIF` instead of `ELSE IF`

Also, there is no need to write this, Oracle already provides you with `LEAST` function, that works on numbers, strings and dates.

```
select LEAST(1,2,3) FROM DUAL;
```